# Docker container doesn't connect to host

Tags: docker, flask, ip, dockerfile, port

I am not able to connect to the docker container from my host machine (Windows 10 Home).

```
#This is how my Dockerfile looks like

FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

After running `docker build -t flask-sample:latest` and then `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-sample`, it shows `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/`, but nothing on my browser shows up.
Also, when I connect to the docker ip address on the port 5000 `(i.e. 192.168.99.100:5000)` everything works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where does docker container run? Linux?

Comment: What URL are you accessing on browser? `http://localhost:5000` or `http://0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: Since you're on Windows Home and using Docker Toolbox, you have to use the `docker-machine ip` address; `localhost` won't work (and `0.0.0.0` doesn't make sense in a URL).

Comment: Alright, so docker doesn't expose the container port to the host port? And there is no way for me to access the container from the host?
All this because I have Windows 10 Home :P. 
Right?